# Getting geotagged photos related to a certain street or close to a gps point

Tags: flickr

I want to be able to display photos of some important touristic attractions that are near certain streets or certain gps coordinates. After digging around i came across Flickr and its API.

They have something but apparently that is not good enough for what i am planning. 
Basically i could use flickr.places.find  method that returns a list of WOE id's and then use them  on flick.photos.search but as per their documentation if i pass a street level address it will return the city that contains the address rather than the street. So that does not do me any good.

Is there any way that i can go around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Flickr.Photos.Search](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) method which has a few attributes that match your needs. I would poke around with this method, which seems to be the one for you.

> ### **Flickr.Photos.Search**
>
> Return a list of photos matching some criteria. Only photos visible to the calling user will be returned. To return private or semi-private photos, the caller must be authenticated with 'read' permissions, and have permission to view the photos. Unauthenticated calls will only return public photos.
>
> #### accuracy (Optional)
>
> Recorded accuracy level of the location information. Current range is 1-16:
>
> - World level is 1
> - Country is ~3
> - Region is ~6
> - City is ~11
> - Street is ~16
>
> #### lat (Optional)
>
> A valid latitude, in decimal format, for doing radial geo queries.
>
> #### lon (Optional)
>
> A valid longitude, in decimal format, for doing radial geo queries.
>
> #### Radius
>
> A valid radius used for geo queries, greater than zero and less than 20 miles (or 32 kilometers), for use with point-based geo queries. The default value is 5 (km).